# How to Label Source upon successful build on Visual Studio Team Services using Github Repository

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was trying to use new Build on Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) from Git repository but couldn't figure out how to label the source upon successful build.

I found, there is option of labeling in Team Services but if we select RepositoryType = Team Foundation Version Control but there is not option if we select RepositoryType = GitHub 
[Screen Shot - Option Details in VSO Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ACPo.png)

I don't know how to label build from Team Services build definition from GIT repository